# Loop and calculate month difference based on criteria

Tags: sql, netezza

I've got a dataset like the below and not really sure where to start. I'm using Aginity Workbench for Netezza and I'm wanting to see when there is an interaction see if there is a conversion within 3 months. Needs to scale across multiple customers.

```
Date        Customer   Interaction  Conversion
1/01/2017   John Smith      1          0
1/02/2017   John Smith                 0
1/03/2017   John Smith                 0
1/04/2017   John Smith                 0
1/05/2017   John Smith                 0
1/06/2017   John Smith      1          0
1/07/2017   John Smith      1          0 
1/08/2017   John Smith                 1            
1/09/2017   John Smith                 0
1/10/2017   John Smith                 0
1/11/2017   John Smith                 0
1/12/2017   John Smith                 0
```

Ideally the output should look like the below  where the conversion is attributed once based on a three month window of interactions. So if there any interactions in subsequent months, then attribute the conversion to the first month of the 3 month window. Also needs to flag what an interaction and conversion happen in the same month.

```
Date        Customer   Interaction  Conversion 3MonthConversion
1/01/2017   John Smith      1          0            0
1/02/2017   John Smith                 0
1/03/2017   John Smith                 0
1/04/2017   John Smith                 0
1/05/2017   John Smith                 0
1/06/2017   John Smith      1          0            1
1/07/2017   John Smith      1          0            
1/08/2017   John Smith                 1            
1/09/2017   John Smith                 0
1/10/2017   John Smith                 0
1/11/2017   John Smith                 0
1/12/2017   John Smith                 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query should work. Please let me know if you face any issue

```
select date,customer, interaction,conversion,
case when interaction=1 and (lead(conversion,1) over (order by date))=1 then 1 
when interaction=1 and (lead(conversion,2) over (order by date))=1 then 1
when interaction=1 and (lead(conversion,3) over (order by date))=1 then 1
else 0 end as threeMonthconversion
from test_month
```

Comment: Edit in the question... Also need the loop to be unique, so if there are interactions in subsequent months, then only mark it once.